# No Module Named 'tkinter' In Code OSS Despite It Being Installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, visual-studio-code, manjaro

I can't get `tkinker` to work in`Code OSS. I use Code OSS on Linux x64 5.13.19-2-MANJARO.

I did the following:

```
pacman -S tk
```

That produced no error. Next I enter:

```
python
```

And the output is:

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Aug 31 2021, 13:28:12)
[GCC 11.1.0] on linux<br>
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I try this:

```py
import tkinter
```

No error message, so it seems to work. I also tried:

```py
tkinter._test()
```

...and it opens a popup window.

But then in Code OSS I did this:

```py
try:
   from Tkinter import *

except ImportError:
   from tkinter import *
```

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/user/Python/lab.py",
line 3, in <module>
    from Tkinter import *   ## notice capitalized T in Tkinter  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/user/Python/lab.py",
line 6, in <module>
    from tkinter import *   ## notice lowercase 't' in tkinter here
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: have you set up Code OSS correctly?

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong with the setup, but I couldn't figure it out. I switched to Visual Studio which now works fine.